# Use Azure OpenID Connect with AD B2C for single sign on

Tags: azure, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure OpenID Connect with Active Directory B2C multi-tenant application for login purpose on my set of applications. Most of the users login using Google social provider of B2C, but for now I'd like to keep the option to use AD open. I use a single B2C application to login to multiple sub-parts of my applications, using different domains, different programming platforms etc - I just allow many return URLs in the B2C app.

What I'd like to achieve is a true single sign-on: possibility to login once and then to access all the sub-applications that use this B2C app.

Currently, when I login to one sub-app and then try to access some other one, I need to choose my Google account (when I'm logged in using Google connector). I'd like to remove the necessity of any human interaction in the process of accessing other parts of the app, when I'm already signed in (of course automatic redirects are fine). Is this possible with B2C/OpenID Connect?

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to remove the part where you have to click?

Comment: For example: I have sub-app foo.example.com, I go there, I'm transferred to Azure's login window, I choose google, login, redirect to foo.example.com. Then I go to bar.example.com that uses the same b2c app. Now, I'm redirected to azure, that transfers me to google connect, where I have to choose google account, and then I go back to bar.example.com. What I'd like to achieve is to skip this google choosing part - Azure would see that I'm logged in and redirect me back to bar.example.com.